# Casting objects coming back from Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax.net

I'm using AJAX.NET and C# ASP.NET

My Soldier class is a type of Person class.

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
 public static Person getPerson(int personId)
 {
    return (Person)personService.getSoldier(personId);
 }
```

This works perfectly well. On the Ajax side, I can get and set the Soldier properties. However, when I send this object back, I can't convert it back to a Soldier object.

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public static Person savePerson(Person person)
{
   Soldier soldier = (Soldier)person;
}
```

This fails. It says it can't convert object Person to Soldier. Is there a way around this because I don't want to create a dozen of save methods for every type? Any help from you would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this aint a problem of ajax. you should have created the class structure accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

"*My Soldier class is a type of Person class*"

That's your problem right there. As `Person` is the base class, it cannot be cast to the child class `Soldier`.

You'll need to write a Convert function in your `Person` class that takes a `Soldier` as a parameter and set the properties individually.

Comment: I tried this:

`[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public static void savePerson(Dictionary<string, object> dictObj)
{
   Soldier soldier = (Soldier)dictObj["soldier"];
}
`
but surprisingly it doesn't work either. Somehow the object comes in as a dictionary<string, object> object also.

Comment: You can't do that as there's no existing direct conversion, just change it back to take a `Person`, then do `Soldier soldier = new Soldier { property = person.property //do this for all properties };`

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is that.

```
Soldier soldier = new Soldier(){soldier.Prop1 = Person.CorrespondingProp;//for all the propertiese};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you created the `Soldier` Class from `Person` class. Your methods return type is `Person` class that is the base class. ***A base class will not have all the attributes of the Child class. But a child class will have all attributes of its Parents.***

Ideally, i you are returning a `Soldier` object,  i would make my method return type as Soldier

```
 public static Soldier getPerson(int personId)
 {
    return personService.getSoldier(personId);
 }
```

Comment: So if I have 10 different types of Person, I have to create 10 methods like this?

Comment: @Johnny : Yes you should do method overriding which is one of the core concepts of OOPS. Have a `Get` method and override it in your derived classes.